# evaluation tool with html and jquery

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

I'm making this evaluation tool that uses radio buttons to select the grade and show the total result, that is the sum of different factors using jquery. I can make the summary, but I dont know how to subtract the previous value selected when I change the grade.

[here is a jsfiddle that shows a simplified version of what I have..](http://jsfiddle.net/xUrJv/8/)

current JQuery

```
 $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    var x= parseInt($(this).val());
    if ($('#weeh:not(:empty)').text()){
        var y= parseInt($('#weeh').text());
        var z= x+y;
        $('#weeh').text(z);
    }else{
        $('#weeh').text(0);
    }

  });
```

The expected behavior is:
For example, If I clicked terrible, it added 4 but if I want to change it to good, it must subtract 4 and add 1 to the result

your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't care about addition and substraction abd what was previously made. Each time any radiobutton is changed, just re-do the whole calculation and display the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
        var x = parseInt($(this).val());
        total += x;
    });
    $('#weeh').text(total);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xUrJv/11/

Comment: You know your JQuery. Thanks

Comment: you dont need the intermediate variable `x`, just do `total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);`

Comment: @stackErr:Yes you can avoid it. But it has no harm in this case :)